# is the Forgetful functor between Algebras and vector Spaces over the same Field not Faithful?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Good Day, i hvae been solving this problem:

"For $K$ a field and $V$ a vector Sapce over $K$, there is an exterior algebra $E(V)$, which is graded, anticonmutative algebra show that $E:Vetc_{K}\rightarrow Alg_{K}$ is the left adjoint of a suitable forgetful functor (one which is not faithful)"

$E:Vetc_{K}\rightarrow Alg_{K}$ is a left adjoint of the forgetful functor due to the Universal property of the exterior algebra.

My question is: why is this forgetful functor is not faithful?

That is the only part that i do not understand. Thnak you for everything.

Comment: Should $E:Vec\to Alg$?

Comment: What exactly is the category $Alg_K$?  If it is the usual category of all associative algebras, the functor $E:Vect_K\to Alg_K$ certainly is not a left adjoint (it doesn't preserve coproducts).  So I assume $Alg_K$ is actually supposed to be the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded (graded-)commutative algebras, or something like that?

Comment: You are correct it was my mistake :-)

Answer (score 4):

The target category of this functor is graded commutative algebras. The forgetful functor is given by taking the subspace of degree $1$, and this is not a faithful functor because it ignores all of the other graded pieces.

Comment: Ok, i get it, i was not sure about the category in which everything was working. Thank you.